# Not able to get external API data through JQuery

Tags: json, jquery, rest, cross-domain

I am trying to get external REST API data through JQuery, but it returs undefined. But when I use my local REST API url, it works. Can anybody explain whats is the problem. Any code sample will be appreciated.

This how i am accessing external Rest API via JQuery.

```
function GetCompanyName(id) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://novacompanysvc.azurewebsites.net/api/companies' + '/' + id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("company" +  x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I see a json result not jsonp

Comment: Could you please paste a sample code ?

Comment: the result is an xml, but you have to get json with callback to get it work...

Comment: I am n newbie in Jquery, please refer me some sample code so that i can get to know more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. result is XML so you need to set `dataType: "text/xml"` and then parse it:

   ```
               success: function (data) {
               if (window.DOMParser)
                     {
                     parser=new DOMParser();
                     xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
                     }
                   else // Internet Explorer
                     {
                     xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                     xmlDoc.async=false;
                     xmlDoc.loadXML(data); 
                     }
   ```
2. I tried to test this but I got: `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that is same-origin restriction so make sure you have access to this API or you will have to do it on the server using CURL in PHP for example.
3. Your are getting id variable in the function you showed in your question, but you are no using it,
   if you want to send it add:

   ,data:{ id:id }

Request should look something like this:

```
      function GetCompanyName(id) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://novacompanysvc.azurewebsites.net/api/companies',
            type: 'GET',
            data:{ id:id },
            dataType: "text/xml",
        success: function (data) {
           if (window.DOMParser)
              {
              parser=new DOMParser();
              xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
              }
            else // Internet Explorer
              {
              xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
              xmlDoc.async=false;
              xmlDoc.loadXML(data); 
              }
           WriteResponse(data);
         },
         error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert('error');
         }
      });
    }
```

Comment: i have also added id at the end of url, but still same error. see my edited question now.

Comment: Your changes are wrong, ` +id ` will create an invalid URL, you should pass variable like i showed you. Also, as i said in number 2 I wasn't bale to get it work because the api page has a origin limit so if you are not in its scope or are in the same domain you will not be able to load data using jquery.

Comment: Thanks! But how we can access Rest api data hosted at an other domain?

Comment: From the user side (using jquery) You can send requests to any page by using $.get $.post $.ajax, but you have to understand that the target page should accept this type of requests - "XMLHttpRequest" if the target page you are posting too would not accept remote requests you will get the deny by "Access-Control-Allow-Origin..."

Comment: The only way assuming the host allows users to load the page, is using  server side request in PHP, ASP, RUBY whatever you need to simulate a user request and sending the correct headers so the webpage will think you are a human user. In PHP you can use CURL, file_get_contents etc... Does it make sense now?